# How do I proceed to add and retrieve and compare data from MySQL database? I'm trying to make a login platform

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to make a login system.

1. The user signs up.
2. username and password get stored in the database
3. user tries to login
4. If successful, the code gives the "Logged in!" message.

Here's the code:

```
import mysql.connector as msqltor

db = msqltor.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='qwerty',
    database='test_db'
)

my_cursor = db.cursor()

def signup():
    username = input("Enter username: ")
    password = input("Enter password: ")

    Q2 = "INSERT INTO credentials(username, password) VALUES (%s, %s)", (username, password)
    my_cursor.execute(Q2)
    db.commit()


def login():
    username = input("Enter username: ")
    password = input("Enter password: ")
    credentials_tuple = (username, password)

    Q3 = "SELECT * FROM credentials where username=%s"
    my_cursor.execute(Q3, (username))

    if credentials_tuple == my_cursor:
        print("Logged in!")
    else:
        print("Error")

Q1 = '''CREATE TABLE credentials(
    username varchar(25),
    password varchar(25)
    )'''

message = '''Welcome to login: \n
1. Signup \n
2. Login \n
'''

user_input = int(input(message))

if user_input == 1:
    signup()
elif user_input == 2:
    login()

# my_cursor.execute(Q1)
```

I get this error message:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 486, in cmd_query
    query = query.encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login.py", line 47, in <module>
    signup()
  File "login.py", line 17, in signup
    my_cursor.execute(Q2)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 266, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 499, in cmd_query
    errno=2055, values=(addr, 'Connection not available.'))
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: Connection not available.
```

Looking at the error, it looks like there is no connection to the MySQL database. However, I don't think that is the problem as I have made sure to connect at the beginning of the code.

Comment: you are trying to insert plain text variables, that is a very bad idea, so use hasging to  save and verify your poasswords

Comment: I don't know python, but my guess is that you're not the first to think of doing this, so what did the other person do?

Answer (score 0):

These lines are the problem:

```
Q2 = "INSERT INTO credentials(username, password) VALUES (%s, %s)", (username, password)
my_cursor.execute(Q2)
```

You want to pass query and values to the cursor's `execute` method like this

```
Q2 = "INSERT INTO credentials(username, password) VALUES (%s, %s)"
my_cursor.execute(Q2, (username, password))
```

You could do this:

```
Q2 = "INSERT INTO credentials(username, password) VALUES (%s, %s)", (username, password)
my_cursor.execute(*Q2)
```

but it's not common, so I would avoid it.

What's happening is that

```
Q2 = "INSERT INTO credentials(username, password) VALUES (%s, %s)", (username, password)
```

creates a `tuple`, and `mycursor.execute` treats this tuple as it's first argument, instead of splitting it into the query and values parts, and this causes the

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

In the login function, this code is problematic:

```
Q3 = "SELECT * FROM credentials where username=%s"
my_cursor.execute(Q3, (username))

if credentials_tuple == my_cursor:
```

The values argument passed to `mycursor.execute` must be a `tuple`, like this:

```
my_cursor.execute(Q3, (username,))  # <- note the comma
```

And then you must fetch the result of the execution for comparison:

```
if credentials_tuple == my_cursor.fetchone():
```